# How to create another column in python pandas from the current table?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, hyperlink, extract

I have the following table:

| ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AB001 | TYPE-A |
| 2 | AB012 | TYPE-A |
| 3 | AB035 | TYPE-B |
| 4 | AB039 | TYPE-B |
| 5 | AB065 | TYPE-A |
| 6 | AB088 | TYPE-B |

I should get the output such that, if ColumnC is TYPE-A then it should save as a separate column (ColumnD) with output [www.website.com/abc/AB001](http://www.website.com/abc/AB001) if it is TYPE-B then it should be [www.website.com/xyz/AB035](http://www.website.com/xyz/AB035). The output table should look like the following:

[image: Output_should_look_like_this]

How do I do that?

Comment: How looks added column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by dictionary for types strings and join together by `+`:

```
#if no match `TYPE-A` or `TYPE-B` added default value no match
s = df['ColumnC'].map({'TYPE-A':'abc','TYPE-B':'xyz'}).fillna('no match')
df['ColumnD'] = ' www.website.com/' + s + '/' + df['ColumnB'].astype(str)
print (df)
   ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC                     ColumnD
0        1   AB001  TYPE-A   www.website.com/abc/AB001
1        2   AB012  TYPE-A   www.website.com/abc/AB012
2        3   AB035  TYPE-B   www.website.com/xyz/AB035
3        4   AB039  TYPE-B   www.website.com/xyz/AB039
4        5   AB065  TYPE-A   www.website.com/abc/AB065
5        6   AB088  TYPE-B   www.website.com/xyz/AB088
```

Comment: @jezael Thank for the help. If I try to implement I het the following error TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str.

Comment: @MuSu18 - Change `df['ColumnB']` to `df['ColumnB'].astype(str)`